# "Access Denied" when attempting to view Excel workbook

Tags: 2013, excel-services

After uploading a workbook to a newly created PowerPivot Gallery, attempting to open the uploaded workbook displays:

[image: Access Denied You do not have permissions to open this file in the browser.]

I am logged in as a Site Collection Administrator and have verified that Excel Services are running with File Access Method - Impersonation, Connection Encryption - Not required, Allow Cross Domain Access - true.

Comment: Of note, this also appears to affect standard Document Libraries - opening the included "Excel Services Sample Workbook" produces the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fair amount of digging, turns out that the Excel Services Application Trusted File Locations only included the default

```
Location = http://
LocationType = Microsoft SharePoint Foundation
...
```

We're running this particular web application over SSL, and needed to add an additional location:

```
Location = https://
LocationType = Microsoft SharePoint Foundation
```

Silly details.